# Notation in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, wavefunction, notation

When we write equations in QM, in certain places, the wave function is represented as $\psi(x,t)$, which is the wave function in position space, and in some other places, it is written as $\Psi(t)$. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no significance in the choice between upper- and lower-case $\psi$ (or $\Psi$) to denote a system's wavefunction. The two are used interchangeably and it is the author's discretion to use either symbol. (On the other hand, of course, one *shouldn't* use the two symbols interchangeably within the same text; if both are used they would refer to different objects.)

There is also little to say, in general, about whether the position $x$ is included as an argument to the wavefunction or not. Some authors may, for example, choose to denote by $\Psi(t)\in\mathcal H$ the Hilbert space state vector, which in the position representation is given by the function $x\mapsto\psi(x,t)$, but this is relatively rare. In general this is a case-by-case matter, but most of the modern literature uses Dirac notation, in which the state vector $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal H$ and its wavefunction $\langle x|\psi\rangle=\psi(x,t)\in\mathbb C$ are distinct objects, shown emphatically distinct by the notation.

Finally, these uses of notation are usually a source of confusion when the wavefunction is split into spatial and temporal parts, such as when setting up a separation of variables scheme for solving the TDSE via the TISE. In such cases, one postulates that the wavefunction $\Psi(x,t)$ of a particle takes the form
$$\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)e^{-i E t/\hbar},$$
in which the temporal and spatial dependences are separated; here if $\psi$ satisfies the TISE then $\Psi$ will satisfy the TDSE. In such situations it's important to keep in mind that $\psi$, whilst a convenient calculational tool, does not represent the state of the system: $\Psi$ does. Beware of notation in such situations, and always check what definition each symbol has been given in the particular text you're reading.